# Input values into array of character pointers using reusable variable

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Disclaimer: This is not meant to be functional, only a pointers exercise.

My program takes random integers and converts them into a string. Then, the string is placed into an array of character pointers.
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void empty_arr(char *);
void fn(char **);

int main()
{
    char *arr[10];
    fn(arr);
    printf("here!\n");
    printf("%c\n", *arr[0]);
    return 0;
}

void empty_arr(char *a)
{
    while (*a != '\0')
    {
        *a = '\0';
        a++;
    }
}

void fn(char **a)
{
    char **p = a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    char temp[10];
    char *t = temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {

            int random = 32 + (rand() % 30);
            *t = (char)random;
            t++;
        }
        *p = temp;
        empty_arr(temp);
        t = temp;
    }
}
```

The result of the program is:
here!

Nothing else is printed after that.

I believe the issue is in this block:

```
*p = temp;
empty_arr(temp);
t = temp;
```

Is there a better way to have the 'random-strings' stored in an array of char pointers?

Comment: Recommend you turn away from the computer and work with pencil and paper to diagram what you want to achieve. Think carefully about what you do at each step of the procedure, and where values are stored and updated. There are a few requisite concepts that this code fails to demonstrate (not the least of which is that `temp[]` begins life uninitialised.)

Comment: `*p = temp;` doesn't make a copy of the data in `temp` it is only assigning a pointer so whatever data `temp` contains at the end all of the pointers point to it. `temp` is not initialized or explicitly zero terminated so `empty_arr` could go right past the end causing undefined behavior. `temp` is also a local variable that is destroyed at the end of the function so the pointers in `arr` in main are no longer valid and dereferencing them is more undefined behavior.

Comment: @RetiredNinja "_at the end all of the pointers point to it_" Actually, only the first. `p` is not incremented nor indexed...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Indeed. Another presumed bug in the bug factory.

Comment: Furthermore `temp` ceases to exist when the function it was allocated inside returns. When that happens, a pointer pointing at `temp` turns invalid and de-referencing it could lead to random output, program crashes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try this code with some changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void fn(char **);

int main()
{
    char *arr[10];
    fn(arr);
    printf("here!\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        free(arr[i]); // Free dynamically allocated memory
    }
    return 0;
}

void fn(char **a)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char *temp = (char *)malloc(4); // Allocate memory for a string of length 3 + 1 for null terminator
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int random = 32 + (rand() % 30);
            temp[j] = (char)random;
        }
        temp[3] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
        a[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

it allocated memory for each string using malloc, copy the generated string into the allocated memory, and make sure to null-terminate the string. Later in the main function, we free the dynamically allocated memory to prevent memory leaks.